# Why do I get UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'routeController'

Tags: java, spring

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RouteController {

    @Autowired
    RouteServiceImpl routeService;

    @GetMapping("/getAllRoutes")
    public List<Route> getAllRoutes(){
        return routeService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class RouteServiceImpl implements RouteService{

    @Autowired
    RouteRepository routeRepository;

    @Override
    public Route insert(Route route) {
        return routeRepository.save(route);
    }

    @Override
    public Route update(Route route) {
        return routeRepository.save(route);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        routeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Route getRouteById(int id) {
        return routeRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Route getRouteByName(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Route> getAll() {
        return routeRepository.findAll();
    }    
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface RouteRepository extends JpaRepository<Route,Integer> {

}
```

Comment: You need to inject `RouteService`, not the implementation

Answer (score 0):

Not linked to your problem, but you should always @Autowire Interfaces and not implementation in your services, also, no need for @Repository on your repo that extends JpaRepository.